# Blockchain taking several days to download to external SSD

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm downloading the blockchain onto the ssd t7 touch which has a max 1000Mbps, so the limiting factor should be my download speed which is 57Mbps. Still the blockchain download has taken a few days and only made 15% progress. Also, why is it saying the blockchain height is 405355, yet the highest downloaded block.dat file is 483? I started the download process by entering command `bitcoind` in my linux terminal. As a sidenote, I am downloading from a chromebook, so not sure if there is a limiting factor there, thought it does have usb3 support.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The initial synchronization is not just a download, but your node also verifies every single transaction that ever happened in the history of Bitcoin. Very likely, the limiting factor is the computation rather than the Download or Disk Writing speed. Please check out the linked questions and let us know if that didn't answer your question.

Comment: thank you, it is the computation I am downloading on a pc now and will just copy over the blockchain to the chromebook. Though it is still taking a few days, it is progressing faster

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for the update